# Django set_password(password) doesn't hash the password

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django documentation, it says that it hashes the password but is not saving it, so I have to save it, as I did. If I create a superuser then everything is ok, but when I try to create a user account, the password gets saved unhashed into the database. I try to use make_password, but that doesn't work either, I get the same result. Do you have any idea?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

from .CHOICES import *
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
country_choice = COUNTRY_CHOICE


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
```

Here is the custom user model.

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields):

    other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')

    if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

    return self.create_user(email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields)
```

Here is the user model.

```
def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, username=username,
                      first_name=first_name, **other_fields)

    user.set_password(password)
    # user.make_password(self.request.data[password])

    user.save()
    return user


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)], unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)], blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)], blank=False)

    # date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True)
    # month = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(12)], blank=False)
    # year = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1942), MaxValueValidator(2017)], blank=False)

    # gender model
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other')], blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICE, blank=False)

    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Then I have forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, EmailInput, PasswordInput
from .models import NewUser


class Person(ModelForm):


    class Meta:

        model = NewUser

        fields = ["username", "email", "first_name", "middle_name", "last_name",
                    "gender", "country", "password"]
```

And views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('profiles')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_one = Person(request.POST)
            Person()

            if form_one.is_valid():
                form_one.save()

                username = form_one.cleaned_data.get("username")

                messages.success(request, f"Account created for {username}!")
                return redirect("login_user")

        else:
            form_one = Person()

        return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {"form_one": form_one})
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Sorry for anything that might upset you, I'm new with Django, and I can't say I'm a python expert, but I try my best. Thank you very much in advance!
Github link to the whole project https://github.com/RazzTazz28/Django-Atlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to save the user after set_password. Set password only creates a hashed pasword, you have to save it

```
if (request.method == 'POST'):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
     
   password = request.POST.get('password') 
  user = User.objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            name=username,  
            password=password,
        )      
  user.set_password(password)
  user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't know where I can find the validated_data parameter. My model doesn't extend the User model, I figure out that I have to create a custom form since I created a custom model. By default, set_password should hash the password, but I guess that the form I have right now cancels that function for some reason. Not sure though.

Comment: But I call user.save() right after set_password. I split the code with a comment, I apologize, I will edit the question right away.

Comment: see edited answer this os the system to register with hashed password

Comment: Lol is actually working! Thank you very much, you are my hero!! Just a small question. Is request.POST.get safe for password management?

Comment: if you use https protocol its save